# Android Custom Socket Deriving from OpenSSLSocketImpl (not SSLSocket)

Tags: android, sockets

Sorry this is such a long question, but it's somewhat involved. Thanks for reading.

I have a custom socket factory and socket class (Android 5.0) that I have developed to perform some specific tasks I need to do at that level.  Here's my socket factory and socket (for brevity, I'm leaving out many of the methods):

```
public class CustomSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {
private final SSLSocketFactory delegate;

public CustomSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
}

private Socket createCustomSocket(Socket socket) {
    if (socket instanceof SSLSocket) {
        socket = new CustomSocket((SSLSocket) socket);
    }
    return socket;
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return createCustomSocket(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException {
    return createCustomSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}


private class CustomSocket extends SSLSocket {

    protected final SSLSocket delegate;

    private CustomSocket(SSLSocket delegate) {
        this.delegate = delegate;
    }
```

I'm using this factory like this:

```
  private void doCustomSocketFactoryWithHttpUrlConnection() {

    try {
        String uri = "https://alice.sni.velox.ch";

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, null, null);
        CustomSocketFactory customSocketFactory = new CustomSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(customSocketFactory);

        URL url = new URL(uri);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        Log.d(TAG, "HTTP Response Code: " + conn.getResponseCode());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }

}
```

This works as expected except when I'm hitting a site that uses [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) like [alice.sni.velox.ch](https://alice.sni.velox.ch). In that case, the site complains (and I confirm with Wireshark) that the SNI TLS headers are not being sent by my app.

Take out my custom socket factory and the headers are sent.

Digging further, I found this code in [okhttp](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/external/okhttp/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/Platform.java) Platform.java class (okhttp classes are used inside HttpsURLConnection).

```
@Override public void enableTlsExtensions(SSLSocket socket, String uriHost) {
     super.enableTlsExtensions(socket, uriHost);
     if (!openSslSocketClass.isInstance(socket)) return;
     try {
       setUseSessionTickets.invoke(socket, true);
       setHostname.invoke(socket, uriHost);
     } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
// snip
}
```

The openSSLSocketClass is being setup this way:

```
Class<?> openSslSocketClass =    Class.forName("com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl");
```

So this code enables SNI and session ticketing but only if the socket extends OpenSSLSocketImpl.

Back to my custom socket, in the debugger I see the class of the socket that is getting passed to the constructor is: com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper (which extends OpenSSLSocketImpl).

So I miss the SNI and session ticketing functionality because my socket extends java.net.ssl.SSLSocket (not OpenSSLSocketImpl).

The best solution that comes to mind is to simply have my CustomSocket extend OpenSSLSocketImpl and add the needed delegate methods but I can't see how to import OpenSSLSocketImpl. It does not appear to be in the standard Android libraries. The Android documentation only discusses SSLSocket and says nothing about OpenSSLSocketImpl.

Is there a way I can have my CustomSocket class extend from OpenSSLSocketImpl that I'm missing?

I realize I can use reflection to call those methods on the "delegate" in my CustomSocket class but I worry about the reliability of that in all cases and where/when exactly to make those calls. Also, if they continue to add new features to the OpenSSLSocketImpl class in new Android releases using a similar method I would miss those features as well.

Thanks for reading all the way through!

Comment: I am having similar issues. Were you able to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

This depends on what functionality you need to implement in your CustomSocket, but you might do the following:

- make CustomSocket extend Socket (no SSL)
- in your socket factory, create a plain custom socket, then wrap a SSL socket around it with `delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose)`
- return the result of `delegate`, it will be of type `com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImplWrapper`

Answer (score -1):

Well maybe I'm not being that useful for you but you can try setting up a  different client like jersey's client or apache http client, especially since Android's own http clients are way too old and should be replaced.

Comment: AndroidHttpClient and Apache HttpClient are deprecated on Android.  HttpURLConnection is the preferred class to use I believe.

Comment: Wel if he's using an outside jar (in his case okhttp) he can try another one. I wasnt saying he should use the built in http client. I think for example the apache http client which was in the original android wasnt even a full release.